# saving deserialized entity remove from database

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I am creating a quiz application and I have this entities:

1. Quiz
2. Question
3. Answer

with relations

Quiz `ManyToMany` Question

Question `OneToMany` Answer

I am editing the questions-answers on the client with serialized entities then when I try to save I deserialize the JSON back to entities.

The entities:

Quiz:

```
 /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Quiz\CoreBundle\Entity\Question", inversedBy="quizes", cascade={"persist", "remove", "merge"})
     * @Type("ArrayCollection<Quiz\CoreBundle\Entity\Question>")
     * @Groups({"public", "admin"})
     */
    protected $questions;
```

Question:

```
/**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Quiz\CoreBundle\Entity\Quiz", mappedBy="questions", cascade={"merge"} )
     * @Exclude()
     */
    protected $quizes;

 /**
    * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Quiz\CoreBundle\Entity\Answer", mappedBy="question", cascade={"remove", "merge", "persist"}, orphanRemoval=true)
    * @Groups({"public", "admin"})
    */
    protected $answers;
```

Answer:

```
/**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Quiz\CoreBundle\Entity\Question", inversedBy="answers", cascade={"merge", "remove"})
     * @Groups({"public", "admin"})
     */
    protected $question;
```

Save Action:

```
 $toSave  = $this->get('request')->getContent();

  /* @var $s Quiz */
  $s =  $serializer->deserialize  ($toSave, 'Quiz\CoreBundle\Entity\Quiz', 'json');

$em->merge($s);
$em->flush();
```

It works fine when I add/update Question/Answer but when I try to remove a question or an answer from a question it doesn't work. Any help ?

Comment: "doesn't work" is kinda broad term. Does the `$s` has valid object? What happens to `$s` when you `merge()`?

Comment: @JovanPerovic yes it's a valid object. Doesn't work means nothing happens in the database.

Comment: Ok then, I assume that `$s` contain valid non-null `id` field. Try doing: `$s2 = $em->merge($s)` and see what will the `$s2` contain then.

Comment: @JovanPerovic `$s2` is the same as `$s`.

Comment: Did you have any luck sorting this out, i'm having the same trouble?